# Downloaded xlsx file with fileSaver is invalid when opened

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, filesaver.js

I have written function where I want to download an xlsx file via a service. Download also works so far. But when I open the file I get the error message file extension or file format is invalid. How can I solve the problem?

Code:

```
// Service
getDownloadPlan(): Observable<any> {
    const url = `/download-plan?sales-plan=0&personnel-plan=0&investment-plan=0&loan-plan=0&material-cost-plan=0`;
    return this.http.get(`${environment.baseUrl}` + url, { responseType: 'blob'});
  }
```

```
// TS
 downloadPlanBwa() {
    this.planBwaService.getDownloadPlan().subscribe(response => {
      const downloadFile: any = new Blob([response], {  type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
      fileSaver.saveAs(downloadFile, 'Plan');
    }, error => console.log('ERROR'),
      () => console.log('SUCCESSFUL')
    );
  }
```

If i use the `MIME-Type application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf-8` this is for the xls-format then it works.

What do I need to change in my code to successfully open xlsx files?

Comment: What do you mean by "If i use the MIME-Type ..." where are you using it?

Comment: If I put in the type MIME type application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf-8 then opening the file works, but only as xls. But I would like to use the above type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' to download and open xlsx files.

Comment: The `type`  option in the `Blob()` constructor doesn't matter here. FileSaver uses the `download` attribute of an `<a>` element, which doesn't look at this property. But xls and xlsx formats are completely different, so if your service returns an xls file, simply setting its extension as `.xlsx` will not magically convert it to an xlsx file.

Comment: I don't quite understand. An example would be nice